# Tutorial for multi core CPU usage in c++ in unix

Tags: c++, unix, performance, traffic-measurement

I would like to know if someone can point me any library or tutorial to work with measurements. In a first moment, **CPU** usage, but latter I will need **network** (I've already found `libcap`, is this good?) and **memory** usages also.

I believe that each of then will be a different library or project, so thanks in advance.

I am currently working in a database monitoring system for UNIX system, in C++.

PS.: is there a way to access the htop **programmatically** from c++?

Pedro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into the `/proc` filesystem. It contains a bunch of plain-text files with system statistics. `/proc/stat` has cpu info, and `/proc/net/*` has network info.

Additionally, `/proc/<pid>/*` contains information about a specific process.

Comment: Well, surely there is nice stuff there. But if I cant get those values from any API, having to parse it, and dont think they can be so usefull anymore. I'm gonna look around. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Thanks, but I could not handle the overhead of parsing the /proc in my application. "Linux has a very nice @file{/proc} filesystem, but reading and parsing @file{/proc} is very slow and inefficient.", as is written in the libgtop white paper. Thanks anyway, looking for proc stuff made me go there.

Comment: man, I was wrong. Going a little bit deeper, I just discovered that even the libgtop uses the /proc filesystem. I was having troubles to add it (which is written in C) to my C++ project, and then discovered that. You answer was right, in the end. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was looking for: http://developer.gnome.org/libgtop/stable/libgtop-white-paper.html